# Which of the following metric is complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Which of the following is/are true ?

1. $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete.
2. $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.
3. $[0,1]$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete.
4. $[0,1]$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.

My Attempt:

Consider a sequence $<\frac{1}{n}>_{n = 2}^\infty$ in $(0,1)$ which is Cauchy sequence but it is not convergent in $(0,1)$ Hence $(0,1)$ is not complete with usual topology.

We know that every compact metric is complete. $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded and hence it is compact. So option 3 is true.
Please help me in other options.

Comment: Completeness is a metric concept, because it depends on Cauchy-ness. With just a topology you usually can't say much about completeness. What you _can_ say is $(0,1)$ with the standard metric is not complete, so point 2 is true. But you haven't disproven point 1.

Comment: "$[0,1]$ is closed and bounded" Every topological space is closed in itself. For closedness to be useful, it must be in relation to a bigger ambient space, and we are given no such thing. And boundedness makes no sense in topology, again you're projecting metric properties onto topological spaces.

Comment: All are true except 4

Answer (score 4):

Hints: Verify that if $h(t)=\min \{t, 1-t\}$ then $|\frac{1 }{h(x)}-\frac{1}{h(y)}|$ is a metric on $(0,1)$ which is complete and has the same topology as the usual topology.

For 2) take the usual metric.

For 3) you have the answer already.

For 4) note that under any other metric for the usual topology $[0,1]$ is compact and compact metric spaces are necessarily complete.

Comment: For your hint to 1), isn't $(\frac{n}{n+1})_{n = 1}^\infty$ a non-converging Cauchy sequence in that metric?

Comment: @Ingix You are right . I was giving the argument for $(0,1]$. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: I guess $|\tan ({\pi}x-\frac\pi 2) - \tan ({\pi}y-\frac\pi 2)|$ would also work, which stretches both "ends" of the interval to $\infty$ and maps the interval to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ingix My argument is a standard one used to show that any $G_{\delta}$ set (in particular  any open set)  in a complte metric space is complete under an equivalent metric.

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1)$ is not complete in the standard *metric* (completeness is a metric notion, not a topological one). As $(0,1) \simeq \Bbb R$ it does have an equivalent complete metric though.

$[0,1]$ in the standard topology and metric is compact and so complete in *any* compatible metric. So for that reason 4 is false; the others are thus true, as we saw.